# Why does this line of code produce the TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, image, autopy

I'm trying to print the color value of a screenshot for some monitoring software. For this I'm using autopy, which has the following command on their website for extracting an rgb value of a pixel.

```
autopy.color.hex_to_rgb(autopy.screen.get_color(100, 100))
```

I don't know much about Python or autopy, so any help is appreciated

Edit: Here's the full error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Scr.py", line 12, in 
    autopy.color.hex_to_rgb(autopy.screen.get_color(100, 100));
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: error may means that `get_color()` returns tuple `(R,G,B)` but `hex_to_rgb()` needs single integer value. Use `print( autopy.screen.get_color(100, 100))` to see what you get.

Comment: That's possible but I took this exact line from https://pypi.org/project/autopy/

Comment: they made mistake in example - or it is old example and currently `get_color()` works different. For me `print( autopy.screen.get_color(100, 100) )` gives `(238, 238, 236)` and I don't need `autopy.color.hex_to_rgb()`

Comment: I sent message to authors with this problem: [mistake in example `autopy.color.hex_to_rgb(autopy.screen.get_color(1, 1))`](https://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopy/issues/34)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `autopy.screen.get_color(100, 100)` you get tuple like `(128, 128, 128)`
it's already in `RGB`. If you need it in hex try this:

```
autopy.color.rgb_to_hex(*autopy.screen.get_color(100, 100))
```

---

**EDIT:** (2019.09.14)

Few weeks ago I sent message to author with this problem

see: [mistake in example autopy.color.hex_to_rgb(autopy.screen.get_color(1, 1))](https://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopy/issues/34)

and now he answered that in next major release this will work as in tutorial.

Comment: Oh wow, from what they said on the website, I thought the get_color would be in hex, but you're absolutely right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got answer from author of this module and in next major release this will work as in tutorial. See: [autopy/issues/34](https://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopy/issues/34#issuecomment-531394484)